# Rails multi level model security

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the need to do the following in Rails to mirror a desktop application:

a User and an Office 'owns' a record, if you don't own the record on a user or office level you're kicked into the public realm.

user gets read,write,delete to the model record
office gets read/write/delete to the model record
other or public gets read/write/delete to the model record

e.g.

UserA owns a model record with read/write/delete
OfficeA owns a model with read/write
other/public gets read

I was wondering if a plugin/gem existed to grant this functionality?

Answer (score 3):

You need an authorization framework like [cancan](http://github.com/ryanb/cancan) or [declarative_authorization](http://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Good if somewhat old survey of plugins here: http://steffenbartsch.com/blog/2008/08/rails-authorization-plugins/  (last updated 2009)

Sounds like you want one that works at the model level.  So choose one that has a "yes" in the "M" column.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Grant](http://github.com/kunklejr/grant).  It's an easy to use, though fairly bare-bones, model-level security framework.  I describe in a little more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12168100/594530).