# How to implement Row Level Security in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've been testing Rails last months and it rocks !
But i have aproblem with how to do RLS ( Row level security )  which is crucial for me. 
I thought i should use ActiveRecord Callbacks but they just can be fired before or after an alteration of the object state, as they say.

I'm going to use PostGresSQL so i should use Views to allow a particular user / organization to see only his rows but i would rather implement the logic of my RLS in rails instead of putting it in my DB directly ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm working on a project now that uses [Grant](https://github.com/nearinfinity/grant).  Though it's not incredibly mature, it does seem to lock things down quite nicely in the models rather than in the controllers, which is where most other 'security' modules for Rails require you to put logic.

Controller-level security really only dictates *where* users can *go*, not *what* they can *see*.  If you accidentally put the wrong resource on a page, you might inadvertently leak info you didn't mean to.

That said, for a small project I'm using [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/), and it works well as long as you're careful not to include resources in views that aren't checked.

Either way you'll need an authentication system to log users in and out.  There are a few: Devise is probably the most widely used.

Answer (score 0):

If for "row level security" you mean allow a user to access a particular row based on his role for the selected row you could have a look at [declarative_authorization (RailsCast)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization), it allows you to define access rules using an high-level DSL. You can even define rules based on "rows" attributes values.

Comment: i'm gonna take the time to test 2 or 3 auhorization solution before i make a choice

Anyway thanks for your very quick answers

Cheers

Philippe

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the user_id from Devise authentication, as added it to my database tables where I wanted to limit by row.

I wrote something up on this at:
http://marktmilligan.tumblr.com/post/78996534776/adding-row-level-security-to-your-rails-app